# Pair my wireless Microsoft Keyboard+Mouse to a different mouse

Tags: wireless-mouse

I'm using Microsoft's Wireless Keyboard+Mouse (Mouse 1000 + Keyboard 800) for my wife's laptop. Now she bought a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000.

How can I pair the new mouse with the current receiver (so we can keep using the current keyboard but with the new mouse)?

Comment: What are the model numbers of the keyboard+mouse and the new mouse? It's quite possible that you've got a system that isn't able to re-pair with a different mouse.

Comment: @MichaelFrank -  Microsoft Wireless Mouse 1000 + Keyboard 800 vs. Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyboard 800.. You cannot. The set is frequency matched at factory.
There are no replacements, nor adjustments or matching procedures.

Comment: Thanks @user3409863. Can you provide a pointer to a relevant reference / KB article?

Answer (score 0):

Receiver and mouse usually both have a "pair" button on them. Press the one on the receiver first, then the one on the mouse.

Comment: No pairing button that I can see, not on the receiver nor on the mouse :(

Comment: If your model does not have pairing button, you're out of luck, it means it's factory paired to it's receiver. But why don't you just use kb and mouse each with it's own receiver?

Comment: ...I was hoping to save that extra USB slot...

Comment: Modern computers have like 6+ usb slots