# Pairing Microsoft keyboard and mouse on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

My mouse 1000 is paired to my keyboard 850. I got a new keyboard 2000. Can I pair my mouse to my new keyboard ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pair my wireless Microsoft Keyboard+Mouse to a different mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/884172/pair-my-wireless-microsoft-keyboardmouse-to-a-different-mouse)

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, I don't think so.

Like other recent Microsoft wireless keyboards and mice, the Microsoft wireless keyboard 2000 comes with a USB wireless receiver that doesn't allow pairing any devices not already paired at the factory, as neither the receiver nor the keyboard have a pairing button.

This also means that if you lose the USB dongle or it stops working, then the keyboard itself becomes useless.

Comment: Thank you Michael